# Encrypt (or hide) an auth token being sent through AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, security

I'm making an ajax request to an API which requires an auth token to be sent in the HTTP headers. Here's what I've got:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://foo.com/bar.json',
  headers: { "Authorization": 'Token token=' + SECRET_KEY },
  dataType: 'json',
  ...
}
```

Thing is I don't want `SECRET_KEY` to be publicly visible if someone were to view the javascript file. Can't seem to find a good workaround, but can't imagine no one else has encountered this... This request is being sent to a Rails app FWIW.

Comment: I'd love to be shown otherwise, but I don't know that there's any way for you to use a secret on the client side, securely. This is usually solved by letting the back-end handle authentication and authorization for each request.

Comment: Thanks @coreyward, that's kind of the impression I've been getting the more I think about this. I'll try to figure out an alternative.